# Ascending Quicksort into Descending order

Tags: java, quicksort

As you can see guys currently I am stuck on this and i do not know how to convert this ascending program into descending order in the same format if someone can help me it would be really kind of you. I am currently a student.

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3};
        quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static void quickSort(int[] arr, int start, int end) {

        int partition = partition(arr, start, end);

        if (partition - 1 > start) {
            quickSort(arr, start, partition - 1);
        }
        if (partition + 1 < end) {
            quickSort(arr, partition + 1, end);
        }
    }

    public static int partition(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        int pivot = arr[end];

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < pivot) {
                int temp = arr[start];
                arr[start] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                start++;
            }
        }

        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = pivot;
        arr[end] = temp;

        return start;
    }
}
```

Comment: you just need to change how you compare your values.

Comment: If you just reverse the comparison operator from `<` to `>`, the order will become descending

Comment: Thank you sir, pardon me but do i have to change both comparison operators in order to make the program displayed in descending order? Because i just tried recently by changing the < to > and it was not in descending order.

Comment: @user14334786 change it where you compare array elements `arr[i] < pivot`

Comment: Thank you for responding sir! God bless you sir!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change

```
if (arr[i] < pivot)
```

To

```
if (arr[i] > pivot)
```

Result :

> 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1

Comment: Thank you so much sir! God bless you sir!